# Why isn't my responsive menu working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a website and I'm very happy with the results.

The menu works quite well on mobile. However, I decided that I wanted to try a menu that disappears when viewd on smaller screens.

Here is the javascript plugin I used [Responsive-Nav][1]

I followed the directions, and when I finished, it messed up my navigation and didnt work. 
Here are both versions

[Site before plugin][2]

[Site after plugin][3]

Im not sure what is causing

Answer (score 3):

You must also define the rules for different screen sizes in css.

In `responsive-nav.css line 11:`

`.nav-collapse li { width: 100%;`

For desktop browser set `width: auto`. This way the menu items will be displayed inline.

Comment: Ok so setting width:auto made my navigation display inline. But im not sure how to define the rules. My break point for mobile is 989px. 990 and above goes to desktop. So how would i define that?

Comment: ok i found where to set the size. But when i do, all that happens is a little thing that says 'menu'